# Load imbalance on kafka receivers in spark-streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

My cluster has 8 nodes (including the node which runs the driver program). Each node has 16 cores. There are 8 Kafka receivers. However, it seems as if only 3 of the receivers has a good "events/second" count. All the others have negligible amount of data coming into them. What could be causing this? Is there any way to fix it so that the load is more evenly balanced?

The data for the receivers is as below:
[image]

Comment: Could you add the code of your Streaming job?

Comment: val kafkaDStreams = (1 to options.numReaderThreads)
      .map { _ => KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, options.zookeepers + options.zookeeperNodePath, options.jobName, topicMap, StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER) }

    println("Repartitioning begin")
    val repartitioned = ssc.union(kafkaDStreams).repartition(options.numExecutors)
    println("Repartitioning completed")